# Active Facebook Session without AccessToken if Facebook App not installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have a strange problem with users who haven't installed the Facebook App (but want to login via Facebook):

I always access the Facebook Session's access token via

```
Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken()
```

It works well for all users who have installed the Facebook app. For users who don't have it installed, it works for the first two calls - after that, the access token turns to an empty String. Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, but somehow I'm not sure what's it all about. Seems like the Session gets garbage collected, and when FB restores it, it does so without getting the access token back again.

This issue only seems to occur with Facebook SDK 3.14, while 3.8 works without problems.

Comment: Haven't really solved it yet. I just kept using FB 3.8 where the problam does not occur.